# Tidal current is setting in the direction of Northeast

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-verbs

I use marine English at work.
Which one is correct?

Tidal current is setting to the direction of Northeast. 
Tidal current is setting in the direction of Northeast.

Comment: ... in a northeasterly direction?

Comment: Neither of them sound fluent; we don't say in *or* to "the direction of northeast".  I would probably just say "to the northeast."

Comment: currents are not said to be setting. The sun sets. I am not 100% sure what you mean but I tried to answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Terminology for tidal currents:

> Alternating horizontal movements of water accompanying the rise and
> fall of astronomical tides in coastal areas are called tidal currents.
> Along the boundaries of an ocean basin (the location of the antinodes)
> tidal ranges and hence, tidal currents are at their maximum.
> Irregulari­ties along the coast modify the rotary motion of tide waves
> so that tidal currents move more directly into and out of rivers and
> harbors. Tidal currents **flow** **in one direction** during part of the tidal
> cycle and **in the oppo­site direction** during the remainder of the tidal
> cycle. **When tidal currents are directed toward the land**, water levels
> rise in harbors and rivers; these are called flood tides. **Tidal
> currents flowing seaward with falling sea levels are called ebb tides**.
> Between flood and ebb tides are slack water periods (little or no
> horizontal movement).
>
> In some coastal areas where the tidal range is relatively large and
> the flood tide enters a narrow bay or channel, a tidal bore forms and
> moves upstream in a river or shallow estuary. A tidal bore is a wall
> of turbulent water, usually less than a meter in height. Tidal bores
> are well known at the mouth of the Amazon River in Brazil, on the
> Severn River in England, and in Turnagain Arm off Cook Inlet, Alaska.
>
> Adapted from DataStreme Ocean and used with permission of the American
> Meteorological Society.

[tides-currents](http://oceanmotion.org/html/background/tides-currents.htm)

Sample sentence: Tidal current is setting to the direction of Northeast.

Better:

- The tidal current is flowing or flows to the northeast. [in a specific place]
- Tidal currents flow to the northeast or northeastward. [in more than one place or in general]
- Tidal currents are directed northeastward.